# typings command not found after installing with nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, typing

If I want to use nodejs with typescript. For this reasen I try to install typings, but when I enter typings command to commandline, only thing I get back is 'command not found'. I try to install typings global and local. I changed global path of npm to my directory: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions.

It is only the missing link. If I run it by tiping the full path (~/.npm-global/bin/typings) it works fine. How to create the missing command? How to tell npm to do it automaticly? At my pc at home it creates this link by its own.